# Cluster detection in a distribution

Tags: distributions, clustering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine different clusters of 1d data from database](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40454/determine-different-clusters-of-1d-data-from-database)

I am trying to detect clusters, i.e. segments on a linear scale, with visibly higher concentration of distribution elements.  Consider the following simplified distribution

```
VAR01=3
VAR02=17
VAR03=18
VAR04=21
VAR05=23
VAR06=44
VAR07=61
VAR08=89
VAR09=90
VAR10=92
VAR11=94
VAR12=117
```

If you put these values on a diagram, you could see that there is a visible concentration (cluster) between 17-23 and 89-94 with VAR01, VAR06, VAR07 and VAR12 being lone outliers.

What are the best techniques in programmatically recognizing such clusters in a distrubution?

Answer (score 5):

Usually, the term **clustering** is used to **multivariate** problems only.

In single dimensions, the problem is *significantly* easier, simply because you can *sort* the data. Any method that comes from multivariate clustering will be easily outperformed by a simpler method that exploits the sortedness of the data set.

You may want to have a look at **natural breaks optimization**, or **kernel density estimation** (look for minima in the KDE, and split there).

Plus, this question has been asked a dozen times before. E.g.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738490/not-random-clusters-in-1d-data-set

[Clustering 1D data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13781/clustering-1d-data)

[How to 'intelligently' bin a collection of sorted data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34242/how-to-intelligently-bin-a-collection-of-sorted-data/34334#34334)

[Alternative to Otsu for dividing data into two groups](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34452/alternative-to-otsu-for-dividing-data-into-two-groups/34454#34454)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738490/not-random-clusters-in-1d-data-set

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147466/what-clustering-algorithm-to-use-on-1-d-data

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869609/cluster-one-dimensional-data-optimally

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513484/1d-number-array-clustering