# Defining bin sizes for plotting histograms

Tags: histogram, binning

Perhaps a basic question, but is there a method or definition of how to choose the optimum bin size for some data with the intent to plot as a histogram?

At present the best option I can think of is to fit distribution functions to the histograms and choose the bin size where the fit is best.

Is there a definition based on the data size or some other metric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rob Hyndman [answers this question well](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/798/calculating-optimal-number-of-bins-in-a-histogram) using the Freedman-Diaconis rule.

I would argue though that there is no "optimal" bin size, and the right number is likely to depend on the question you're trying to answer by plotting a histogram. To that end, plotting the data with several different bin sizes is probably a good idea.

Also check out [kernel density estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) as another approach which doesn't invoke bins at all, but does require you to select an appropriate kernel and bandwidth.